# Can't access record id field

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

I've imported an Excel spreadsheet that has one-to-many relationship entries. For example, a business has one legal name but multiple locations with a DBA name for each location. There is a record for each DBA location. I'm filtering through the input data creating a single entry for each legal business name in one table and creating a business location entry for each DBA location. I'm trying to manually assigned the record ID for a legal business into each of its DBA business location records.

Here is my problem. When I try the following:

```
@dba_business.legal_business_id = @legal_business.id
```

I get the following error.

> undefined method `id' for #<LegalBusiness::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fe1f2cc3770>

I tried the following but the @dba_business.legal_business_id ends up blank instead of putting the record ID value in the field.

```
@dba_business.legal_business_id = @legal_business
```

Legal_Business is set up with has_many :dba_business and DBA_business :belongs_to legal_business.

I used the debug.inspect command to see the attributes, `logger.debug "LEGAL BUSINESS: #{@legal_business.inspect}"`, and you can clearly see the ID field defined as an attribute.

```
LEGAL BUSINESS: *#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<LegalBusiness id: 58722, user_id: nil, legal_name:.........*
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3, Rails 4.1, Ruby 2.1.1 with rvm. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend reading this: http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

and then look at your debug message:

```
LEGAL BUSINESS: *#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<LegalBusiness id: 58722, user_id: nil, legal_name:.........*
```

HINT: where are brackets `[]` usually used?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The result of a quick copy-and-paste. I had an "@" in the wrong place.

@object = @Model.create()

and it should have been

@object = Model.create ()